# MATLAB R2020b: libmwlaunchermain.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory when running compiled binary

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

I compiled my MATLAB script using mcc and I'm trying to run the binary in a Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch) environment.

I only have the full MATLAB installation available and don't have (and don't want) the MATLAB Runtime, as I believe the full MATLAB installation comes with the Matlab runtime already.

I get the following error when I try running the binary.

```
root@me:/home/matlab/my-project/build-binary# bash run_my_project.sh /usr/local/matlab/R2020b/bin/glnxa64
------------------------------------------
Setting up environment variables
---
LD_LIBRARY_PATH is .:/usr/local/matlab/R2020b/bin/glnxa64/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/matlab/R2020b/bin/glnxa64/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/matlab/R2020b/bin/glnxa64/sys/os/glnxa64:/usr/local/matlab/R2020b/bin/glnxa64/sys/opengl/lib/glnxa64
./tfda_cli: error while loading shared libraries: libmwlaunchermain.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I can confirm that the file it's not able to find is indeed in the directory I pointed it to.

```
root@me:/home/matlab/my-project/build-binary# ls /usr/local/matlab/R2020b/bin/glnxa64 | grep libmwlaunchermain.so
libmwlaunchermain.so
```

Other questions about this topic assume that the MATLAB Runtime is installed, which isn't the case for me since I only have the full MATLAB installation.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Use `./run_my_project.sh /usr/local/matlab/R2020b` (note how it adds `bin/glnxa64` for you).

Comment: @CrisLuengo that did the trick - thank you so much! If you want to post this as answer I'm happy to accept.